# How to make two boxes vertically aligned? HTML,CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

I am trying to make two boxes vertically align when viewed on a **smaller screen**, so something like this:

[image]

The above image is just an example, see how the two boxes are vertically aligned? I am trying to accomplish that but with the following code:

```css
/* What I Am Working On Page */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body20{
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  background: transparent;
}
.skill-bars{
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 97%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.skill-bars{
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 200% !important;
 }
}
.skill-bars .bar{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.skill-bars .bar:first-child{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info span18{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.skill-bars .bar .progress-line{
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
              0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}
@keyframes animate {
  100%{
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar .progress-line span18{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
}
/* SET THE ANIMATED CLASS TO GET IT TO ANIMATE */
.bar .progress-line span18.animated{
    animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}
.bar .progress-line.html span18{
  width: 84%;
}
.bar .progress-line.css span18{
  width: 76%;
}
.bar .progress-line.jquery span18{
  width: 91%;
}
.bar .progress-line.python span18{
  width: 59%;
}
.bar .progress-line.mysql span18{
  width: 70%;
}
/* ADDED ANIMATED HERE SO ANIMATES ONLY WHEN IN THE VIEWPORT */
.progress-line span18.animated::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
    animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
.progress-line span18.animated::after{
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes showText2 {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.progress-line.html span18::after{
  content: "84%";
}
.progress-line.css span18::after{
  content: "76%";
}
.progress-line.jquery span18::after{
  content: "91%";
}
.progress-line.python span18::after{
  content: "59%";
}
.progress-line.mysql span18::after{
  content: "70%";
}


/* -----------------second box------------------------- */

.skill-bars1 {
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 97%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.skill-bars1{
  width: 200% !important;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
 }
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 .info1 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 .info1 span19 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 .progress-line1 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar1 .progress-line1 span19 {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
}
.bar1 .progress-line1 span19.animated1{
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;

}

.bar1 .progress-line1.html1 span19 {
  width: 61%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.css1 span19 {
  width: 50%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.jquery1 span19 {
  width: 68%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.python1 span19 {
  width: 82%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.mysql1 span19 {
  width: 98%;
}

.progress-line1 span19.animated::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress-line1 span19.animated::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText2 {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.progress-line1.html1 span19::after {
  content: "61%";
}

.progress-line1.css1 span19::after {
  content: "50%";
}

.progress-line1.jquery1 span19::after {
  content: "68%";
}

.progress-line1.python1 span19::after {
  content: "82%";
}

.progress-line1.mysql1 span19::after {
  content: "98%";
}
```

```html
 <h2>What I am Working On</h2>
        </div>
      <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
  <div class="skill-bars">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Harvard CS50 Course</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line html">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Youtube Channel (Java Tutorials)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line css">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>C++</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line jquery">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Java</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line python">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Web Development (Front-End)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line mysql">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- second box -->
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
       <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
  <div class="skill-bars1">
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Competitive Chess (School Club)</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 html1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Linkedin Learning</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 css1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>GitHub Side Projects</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 jquery1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Computer Science and Math Tutoring</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 python1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Reading "Cracking The Coding Interview" &#128522</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 mysql1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

On my end, when I am inspecting my website and viewing it on a smaller screen, this is my output:

[image]

What property am I missing in my css? I know the css code is a bit long, but only consider the media queries which I have. One is for `skill-bars` and other is for `skill-bars1`. In the media queries, what would I put to make them vertically aligned? Because on my end, they are appearing like in the image I sent above. Any suggestions?

### Edited

[image]

### Edited 2

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OUOme4fLTvP6m2kw3G7DG0MV0ALZS4Zf/view

The problem:

I have two sites open: One is `hussaino.me` and other is `https://hussainomerca-6.hussainomer1.repl.co/`

The second box in `https://hussainomerca-6.hussainomer1.repl.co/` is not aligned as the second box in `hussaino.me`

I go back and forth between the sites so that you can see the difference in the second boxes in both sites, the second box in `hussaino.me` is a bit wider and **I want that**

What I think the problem is: in the `css` file, before the changes, I added `width: 97%` to `skill-bars` and also `skill-bars1`. Now, when we made changes, we have `master` and I have set the width inside of that to be `98.6%` which overrides the `skill-bars` and `skill-bars` widths. So, how can I make it so the two boxes have the `width: 97%`?

Code:

```css
.master {
  display: flex;
}

.master div {
  width: 98.6%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .master {flex-flow: wrap;}
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body20{
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  background: transparent;
}
.skill-bars{
  padding: 25px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.skill-bars{
  padding: 25px 30px;
 }
}
.skill-bars .bar{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.skill-bars .bar:first-child{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info span18{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.skill-bars .bar .progress-line{
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
              0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}
@keyframes animate {
  100%{
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar .progress-line span18{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
}
/* SET THE ANIMATED CLASS TO GET IT TO ANIMATE */
.bar .progress-line span18.animated{
    animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}
.bar .progress-line.html span18{
  width: 84%;
}
.bar .progress-line.css span18{
  width: 76%;
}
.bar .progress-line.jquery span18{
  width: 91%;
}
.bar .progress-line.python span18{
  width: 59%;
}
.bar .progress-line.mysql span18{
  width: 70%;
}
/* ADDED ANIMATED HERE SO ANIMATES ONLY WHEN IN THE VIEWPORT */
.progress-line span18.animated::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
    animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
.progress-line span18.animated::after{
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes showText2 {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.progress-line.html span18::after{
  content: "84%";
}
.progress-line.css span18::after{
  content: "76%";
}
.progress-line.jquery span18::after{
  content: "91%";
}
.progress-line.python span18::after{
  content: "59%";
}
.progress-line.mysql span18::after{
  content: "70%";
}


/* -----------------second box------------------------- */

.skill-bars1 {
  padding: 25px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.skill-bars1{
    padding: 25px 30px;
 }
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 .info1 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 .info1 span19 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 .progress-line1 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar1 .progress-line1 span19 {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
}
.bar1 .progress-line1 span19.animated1{
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;

}

.bar1 .progress-line1.html1 span19 {
  width: 61%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.css1 span19 {
  width: 50%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.jquery1 span19 {
  width: 68%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.python1 span19 {
  width: 82%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.mysql1 span19 {
  width: 98%;
}

.progress-line1 span19.animated::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress-line1 span19.animated::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText2 {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.progress-line1.html1 span19::after {
  content: "61%";
}

.progress-line1.css1 span19::after {
  content: "50%";
}

.progress-line1.jquery1 span19::after {
  content: "68%";
}

.progress-line1.python1 span19::after {
  content: "82%";
}

.progress-line1.mysql1 span19::after {
  content: "98%";
}
```

```html
 <div class="master">
      <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
  <div class="skill-bars">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Harvard CS50 Course</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line html">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Youtube Channel (Java Tutorials)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line css">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>C++</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line jquery">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Java</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line python">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Web Development (Front-End)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line mysql">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <!-- second box -->
      <div data-aos="fade-up">
       <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
  <div class="skill-bars1">
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Competitive Chess (School Club)</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 html1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Linkedin Learning</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 css1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>GitHub Side Projects</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 jquery1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Computer Science and Math Tutoring</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 python1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Reading "Cracking The Coding Interview" &#128522</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 mysql1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
            </div>
```

I removed the `.master div` and added `width: 97%` to both `skill-bars` and `skill-bars1` but this is what my output looks like:

It actually works, but how would I make the second box be like first box like in terms of width?

[image]

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Please update the snippet to a [mcve]

Comment: Also your animation takes 20 seconds or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an important recommendation *Reutilize Classes*. You are duplicating your css by adding multiple classes, that uses the same styles, when one should be enough. For example, instead of `.skill-bars .bar { margin: 20px 0; } .skill-bars1 .bar1 { margin: 20px 0; }`, you could have use the `skill-bars` on both boxes.

Now, in order to achieve what you want, I would add both boxes inside a `div`, which will help maintain the desired layout.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .container {flex-flow: wrap};
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class=box></div>
  <div class=box></div>
</div>
```

Using `flex-flow: wrap`, should be enough to add a new row. Please let me know if this was what you intended.

**EDIT**

As request, using your code.

```css
/* What I Am Working On Page */
.master {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .master {flex-flow: wrap;}
}

.master > div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body20{
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  background: transparent;
}
.skill-bars{
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 97%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.skill-bars{
  padding: 25px 30px;
 }
}
.skill-bars .bar{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.skill-bars .bar:first-child{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info span18{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.skill-bars .bar .progress-line{
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
              0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}
@keyframes animate {
  100%{
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar .progress-line span18{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
}
/* SET THE ANIMATED CLASS TO GET IT TO ANIMATE */
.bar .progress-line span18.animated{
    animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}
.bar .progress-line.html span18{
  width: 84%;
}
.bar .progress-line.css span18{
  width: 76%;
}
.bar .progress-line.jquery span18{
  width: 91%;
}
.bar .progress-line.python span18{
  width: 59%;
}
.bar .progress-line.mysql span18{
  width: 70%;
}
/* ADDED ANIMATED HERE SO ANIMATES ONLY WHEN IN THE VIEWPORT */
.progress-line span18.animated::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
    animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
.progress-line span18.animated::after{
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes showText2 {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.progress-line.html span18::after{
  content: "84%";
}
.progress-line.css span18::after{
  content: "76%";
}
.progress-line.jquery span18::after{
  content: "91%";
}
.progress-line.python span18::after{
  content: "59%";
}
.progress-line.mysql span18::after{
  content: "70%";
}


/* -----------------second box------------------------- */

.skill-bars1 {
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 97%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.skill-bars1{
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
 }
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 .info1 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 .info1 span19 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.skill-bars1 .bar1 .progress-line1 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar1 .progress-line1 span19 {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
}
.bar1 .progress-line1 span19.animated1{
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;

}

.bar1 .progress-line1.html1 span19 {
  width: 61%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.css1 span19 {
  width: 50%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.jquery1 span19 {
  width: 68%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.python1 span19 {
  width: 82%;
}

.bar1 .progress-line1.mysql1 span19 {
  width: 98%;
}

.progress-line1 span19.animated::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress-line1 span19.animated::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText2 {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.progress-line1.html1 span19::after {
  content: "61%";
}

.progress-line1.css1 span19::after {
  content: "50%";
}

.progress-line1.jquery1 span19::after {
  content: "68%";
}

.progress-line1.python1 span19::after {
  content: "82%";
}

.progress-line1.mysql1 span19::after {
  content: "98%";
}
```

```html
<div class=master>
<h2>What I am Working On</h2>
</div>
<div class="master">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
  <div class="column1">
  <div class="row1">
  <div class="skill-bars">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Harvard CS50 Course</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line html">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Youtube Channel (Java Tutorials)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line css">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>C++</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line jquery">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Java</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line python">
        <span18></span18>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span18>Web Development (Front-End)</span18>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line mysql">
        <span18></span18>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
      <!-- second box -->
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
       <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
  <div class="skill-bars1">
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Competitive Chess (School Club)</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 html1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Linkedin Learning</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 css1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>GitHub Side Projects</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 jquery1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Computer Science and Math Tutoring</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 python1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1">
      <div class="info1">
        <span19>Reading "Cracking The Coding Interview" &#128522</span19>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line1 mysql1">
        <span19></span19>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: It still is not working, could you show me an example with my code above?

Comment: Last request, could you please have the output of your code be the same as the picture I just added in my post? The alignment of the boxes is off in your code and I want it to be exactly as the picture I just added under "Edited". After this, I will accept and upvote your answer because you have greatly helped me figure out something I couldn't for two days lol

Comment: You want them to have the same width. Is that it? As they do have the same alignment as the first picture.

Comment: Yeah same width, and on any large screen, they should appear as the picture I sent

Comment: Now, they have the same size and are aligned as the first picture.

Comment: Nono, they should have the same width and alignment as the picture I added under "Edited". Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Hey, if you have time can you look at this question which is an issue I am facing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049963/alignment-of-box-issue-in-html-css

Comment: The issue you are facing might be the result of an additional `div`. The second box is inside a `div class=container` which doesn't differs from the first box. Removing that div should do the trick.

Comment: Can you post an updated answer in the question, and I can also upvote and accept your answer there? It is because I have a lot of unwanted code so I can better see and remove when I can refer to your code as well

Comment: Hey, I added a video + explanation in the above post to describe my problem. If you have spare time, can you please take a look at it? Its under "Edited 2". I promise I won't bug you again, this is the last time as its very urgent. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: I added more explanation to make my problem seem clear and easy to understand

Comment: could you take a look at this question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074754/image-stretch-in-html-css?noredirect=1#comment120319714_68074754